# Oracle - best way to return from a procedure an OUT SYS_REFCURSOR with all the rows and columns deleted from a table

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures

I want to do something like this:

```sql
create or replace procedure get_deleted_rows(result_set OUT SYS_REFCURSOR) is
begin
 delete from table1
 where start_date >= sysdate - 30 and start_date <= sysdate
 returning * bulk collect into result_set;
end;
```

I saw that creating a type `table of...` and using `bulk collect` into a declared variable of this type was a way to go. But, this table I'm deleting has several columns and doing this would generate a lot of complexity for me to place it in production.

Is there a more simple way to return all the rows from a delete from a procedure?

Comment: I think you can have an Archival table to store the data getting deleted and then can return results from that table.

Comment: But then this is another table to manage. Isn't there a simpler way?

Comment: As you're deleting the rows, how can a cursor read them for you? Maybe you can try to create this refcursor using an AS OF query (sorry, no access to a db now to check or give sample code)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ... and doing this would generate a lot of complexity for me

I'm afraid that you'll just have to accept it.

Here's an example of how to do it.

Sample table; I'll delete rows for employees whose salaries are higher than 2000.

```
SQL> select * from test order by sal;

ENAME             SAL STARS
---------- ---------- ----------
SMITH             800
JAMES             950
ADAMS            1100 *
WARD             1250 *
MARTIN           1250 *
TURNER           1500 *
ALLEN            1600 *
BLAKE            2850 **        --> delete Blake, Jones and Scott
JONES            2975 **
SCOTT            3000 ***

10 rows selected.
```

Let's start:

```
SQL> create or replace type t_row is object
  2    (ename varchar2(10), sal number, stars varchar2(10));
  3  /

Type created.

SQL> create or replace type t_tab as table of t_row;
  2  /

Type created.
```

Procedure:

```
SQL> create or replace procedure p_test (par_rc out sys_refcursor)
  2  is
  3    l_tab t_tab;
  4  begin
  5    delete from test
  6    where sal > 2000
  7    returning t_row(ename, sal, stars) bulk collect into l_tab;
  8
  9    open par_Rc for select * from table (l_tab);
 10  end;
 11  /

Procedure created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> var l_rc refcursor
SQL>
SQL> exec p_test(:l_rc);

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> print l_rc

ENAME             SAL STARS
---------- ---------- ----------
JONES            2975 **                   --> Deleted, as expected
BLAKE            2850 **
SCOTT            3000 ***
```

What's left?

```
SQL> select * from test order by sal;

ENAME             SAL STARS
---------- ---------- ----------
SMITH             800
JAMES             950
ADAMS            1100 *
WARD             1250 *
MARTIN           1250 *
TURNER           1500 *
ALLEN            1600 *

7 rows selected.

SQL>
```